# How to prevent access of web folder from browser in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, redirection

When I visit URL of my Magento store like **http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/default/** then it shows all sub-folder listings on browser like shown in below image-

[image]

How can I prevent them from showing like this ?

Answer (score 2):

This comes from your webserver configuration. If you are using Apache, directory listing is enabled with `Options Indexes`, for nginx it is `autoindex on`. You have to remove this from the virtual host configuration, or use `Options -Indexes`/`autoindex off` to turn directory listing off explicitly.

If you don't know where to find this configuration, ask your admin/hoster, it depends on the system.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve my GOAL using .htaccess? By doing some changes in it.

Comment: A .htaccess file with `Options -Indexes` could work, but it depends on the `AllowOverride´ setting, if you actually can override it in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of server you can simply place index.php with Access Denied echo Error message.

Comment: This is not really a full answer, more like a comment. It does not include how to implement this.

Comment: Implementation is too simple just place index.php file that contains echo "Access Denied";

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess file in the target folder with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```